# Connection issue with SSIS package pointing to SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

We have an SSIS package running inside a SQL Server 2008 environment.
The package is supposed to transfer data to a SQL 2012 table.
The package however often encounters the "TCP connection forcibly closed by remote host" or "Communication link failure" errors. And when it successfully completes, it runs in 4-5 hrs,
which does not happen to other packages.
Resources/resolutions on the web seem very specific to their issue.

Is this problem related to environment of the destination being SQL 2012?
Or can this be solved by disabling priority boost in the 2012 server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to establish the communication between the servers using the SQL Native Client [Named pipes] provider. You can set up the communication channels using the Server Configuration Utility.

HTH, let us know !

Greg.